# How can I make nginx handle fastcgi requests concurrently?

Tags: nginx, fastcgi

Using a minimal fastcgi/nginx configuration on ubuntu 18.04, it looks like nginx only handles one fastcgi request at a time.

```
# nginx configuration
location ~ ^\.cgi$ { 
    # Fastcgi socket
    fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/fcgiwrap.socket;

    # Fastcgi parameters, include the standard ones
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}
```

I demonstrate this by using a cgi script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Content-Type: text";
echo;
echo;
sleep 5;
echo Hello world
```

Use curl to access the script from two side-by-side command prompts, and you will see that the server handles the requests sequentially.

How can I ensure nginx handles fastcgi requests in parallel?

Comment: https://www.nginx.com/blog/thread-pools-boost-performance-9x/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have Nginx handles fastcgi requests in parallel you'll need several things:

1. Nginx >= 1.7.1 for threadpools, and this configuration:

> ```
> worker_processes N; // N as integer or auto
> ```

where `N` is the number of processes, `auto` number of processes will equate the number of cores; if you have many IO, you might want to go beyond this number (having as many processes/threads as cores is not a warranty that the CPU will be saturated).

> In terms of NGINX, the thread pool is performing the functions of the delivery service. It consists of a task queue and a number of threads that handle the queue. When a worker process needs to do a potentially long operation, instead of processing the operation by itself it puts a task in the pool’s queue, from which it can be taken and processed by any free thread.

Consequently, you want to choose `N` bigger than the maximum number of parallel requests. Hence you can pick say 1000, even if you got 4 cores; for IO, threads will only take some memory, not much CPU.

2. When you have many IO requests with large latencies, you'll also need `aio threads` in the `'http'`, `'server'`, or `'location'` context, which is a short for:

> ```
> # in the 'main' context
> thread_pool default threads=32 max_queue=65536;
>
> # in the 'http', 'server', or 'location' context
> aio threads=default;
> ```

You might see that switching from Linux to FreeBSD can be an alternative when dealing with slow IO. See the reference blog for deeper understanding.

[Thread Pools in NGINX Boost Performance 9x! (www.nginx.com/blog)](https://www.nginx.com/blog/thread-pools-boost-performance-9x/)

Answer (score 5):

Nginx is a non-blocking server, even when working with `fcgiwrap` as a backend. So the number of nginx processes should not be the cause of the problem. The real solution is to increase the number of `fcgiwrap` processes using the `-c` option.
If `fcgiwrap` is launched with `-c2`, even with one Nginx worker process, you can run 2 cgi scripts in parallel.

Comment: This works, but if you are using `spawn-fcgi` to launch `fcgiwrap` then you need to use `-f "/usr/bin/fcgiwrap -c 5"` to get it to work - NOTE: the double quotes