# How can I get niginx fastcgi to run requests in parallel?

Tags: nginx, fastcgi

I'm trying to get nginx to serve more than one connection at a time, with a fasgcgi backend.

This [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66099376/17136434) might contain the answer, but neglects to say **where** that option could be configured. All the options I see are in config files. Where would I put command line options like "-c 2"? It's not nginx -c, that's config. I don't see anyplace that looks like it would take command line options.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks like I don't need the above linked answer. The setting is

```
FCGI_CHILDREN
```

And the reason I had a bit of finding this is that this setting is not in nginx's config, it's in fcgiwrap's config. That is (on my machine) in /etc/init.d/fcgiwrap. Change FCGI_CHILDREN to something larger than 1.

```
FCGI_CHILDREN="5"
```

Just changing that to greater than one allow me to run more than one request at a time.

The linked answer mentions

```
if you are using spawn-fcgi to launch fcgiwrap then you need to use -f "/usr/bin/fcgiwrap -c 5"
```

but I did not have to do that.